# Python range function in the for loop - what is the stop parameter doing here?

Tags: python, for-loop, parameters, range

```
i = 0
while (i < 5):
    for j in range(i, 1, -1):
        print(j)
    print('*')
    i = i + 1
```

For this section of code I assumed that the output would be something like this:

```
0
*
1
0
*
2
1
0
etc.
```

I don't understand why the input is in fact:

```
*
*
2
*
etc.
```

I know that the the parameters are `range([start,] stop[, step])` but I just don't quite understand how the stop parameter is working here when its value is 1. What is the stop parameter doing exactly?

Comment: Why do you expect the ranges to include `0` when you have them counting down to `1`?

Answer (score 2):

Your first two iterations are `range(0, 1, -1)` and `range(1, 1, -1)`, neither of which contains anything.

Similarly, `range(2, 1, -1)` is `[2]` and so on. Python ranges don't include their ending element.

Comment: Why do these not contain anything?

Comment: There are no numbers in those ranges to print out

Comment: @shoven In the range function the stop parameter is not included in the range. For example `range(0, 3)` would evaluate to `[0,1,2]`.

Comment: So to clarify: because the stop value is 1, 0 and 1 cannot step down to any value, because 1 is not included? Is this why there are no numbers in those ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Range starts at `start` and then takes successive steps until it reaches stop (Note that stop isn't yielded).

So,

```
range(0, 1, -1)
```

starts at 0, and takes steps until the value is <= 1 (<= because the step is negative.  If the step was positive, then it would be >=).  As soon as that condition is `True`, the element doesn't get yielded (or appended to the list) and range stops.

Answer (score 1):

Read `stop` as "stop before" and you're done. It's a convention, ok?

It seems that this particular convention somehow puzzles you and, surprise! it puzzled me too when I began with python.  You will come to good terms with it because you'll see it's the logical thing to do when you count sequences starting from 0.

---

*Post* <sub>(very post)</sub> *Scriptum*: and when you'll come to good terms with it, you'll realize that the celebrations for the New Millennium happened 365 days too soon…

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
for i in range(0, 1, -1):
    print i
```

and

```
for i in range(1, 1, -1):
    print i
```

produce nothing, because there are no numbers in those ranges to print. That's why your code goes straight to `print('*')` for the first two iterations of the while loop.

Breaking it down further:

```
for i in range(2, 1, -1):
    print i # prints 2

for i in range(3, 1, -1):
    print i # we get [3, 2]
```

and so on..